# How do you disable the CPU window in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, debugging, ide, window, cpu

When stepping a program in Delphi 7, the CPU window sometimes pops up and then steps through that instructions. I find this an annoyance as I wish to only step Pascal Code.

Does anyone know how to disable this CPU pop-up?

***I would not be sorry if this window never ever shows.***

It did not happen on Delphi 5 which was my previous IDE that I used for Delphi. I do use the Step-Over button mostly and only step-into when wanting to get into detail of a used (pascal) unit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delphi does not, by default, step into the CPU window. So the answer to your question is not that it can not be done. Maybe the question should be: What did I do that causes this.

**EDIT**:
From the comments I understand that it happens when you press pause to break in the debugger.
It is not strange that it stops on the exact place where it was executing when you hit pause.
This could very well be in some Windows code for which you do not have the source.
By choosing `Run -> Run to Next Source Line` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> your program will execute a bit further until it hits some code for which it does have source code.

This is the answer to your problem, but remember that you could have breaked in a spot where you never reach a next source line.

Comment: I often click the pause button and end up immediately in the CPU window - it is difficult then to step to get to the next "pascal bit" as it often steps through endless reams of CPU addresses. This is what I want to go away.

Comment: Ah! But that is not what the question said. I updated my answer with a solution for this case.

Answer (score 11):

In RAD studio 2009, you can got to `Tools->Options->Debugger Options->Codegear Debuggers`. In `General`, select `Ignore non-user breakpoints`.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. There is also "Debug spawned processes" on the same dialog. If the CPU debugger says "Spawned Process" at the top, then you can uncheck that option. That was the problem I had.

Comment: I have the issue, CPU window automatically spawned when debugging and never goes to code section. Restarting IDE fixed.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that i resolved it: added to the registry:
HKCU\Software\Borland|Delphi\7.0\Debugging: EnableCPU (stringvalue):0

Comment: It doesn't work on mine - It still breaks into the CPU windows when I "pause"

Comment: Maybe it does help for other things, so I give you a vote up.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/software/Borland/Delphi/6.0/Debugging/Integrated Debugging = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You fall into the CPU-Window when there are no Debug-Informations for the current Unit.

Try to enable the Debug-DCU's (in Project/Options.../Compiler). If you haven't checked the other debug options, activate them also.

Comment: That's not going to cure it. The debugger often steps into Windows code as well. No debug info for that unless you're running a debug enabled copy of Windows as well.

Comment: If the Debug-DCU's are enabled, you will first trace into the Windows-Unit of Borland/CodeGear. If you then step into an API-Call, Delphi will pop up the CPU-Window. Just step over the API-Call.