# DELPHI IDE - Stopping F12 from bring up the ‘CPU’ Window

Tags: delphi

I am busy developing a Delphi App that uses F12

When I am running the software under the Delphi IDE and press F12 the program stops and the ‘CPU’ window opens up

What can I do to stop the Delphi IDE from doing  this when F12 is pressed ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you disable the CPU window in Delphi 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178068/how-do-you-disable-the-cpu-window-in-delphi-7)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change the value of this registry key..

> `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\UserDebuggerHotKey`

..to 0x13 (19 in decimal). This changes the key from f12 to pause/break. You will need to reboot for this change to take effect.

Reference: [this blog post](http://blogs.teamb.com/deepakshenoy/2004/12/17/2204).
The MS link in the post is broken, [so here's a fixed one](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windows2000serv/reskit/regentry/11498.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: For me, that registry key is set to 0x00000000.. and the blog's link to microsoft support is broken.

Comment: Here's a non-broken link:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windows2000serv/reskit/regentry/11498.mspx?mfr=true
0x00000000 = F12

Comment: Craig, you should put the non-broken link directly in your answer rather than in a comment to it.

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Note that it does require a reboot though.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me editing your post - I've been looking for this tweak for a long time, and I'd hate someone else to miss it because a blogger didn't pay his hosting bill :)

Comment: No, I don't mind you editing the post since you improved it. :)