# Debugger displays useless info on user breaks

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2009

It's a silly point, but I haven't been able to find the answer by myself :

In delphi 2009, when I hit the "pause" button ("Suspend program execution") while debugging, the IDE pops the CPU window, and shows me the execution point and stack of the thread which actually stopped the execution, instead of the main thread - which is almost always what I would like to see.

I then have to manually go to the "threads" window, and double click on the "Main" line to have the debugger display the stack I am concerned with.

Is there a setting to tell the IDE "Hey, when I break manually, show me the infos about the main thread, not about the debugger thread"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178068/how-do-you-disable-the-cpu-window-in-delphi-7) deals with the same issue.  Sounds like the best solution is to use "**Run/Run to next source line**" if that still works in your version of Delphi.  It doesn't sounds like the registry edit suggested there (or [here](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/delphi/delphi_ide/f174.shtml)) has been a consistent solution, but it's possible that people are using the wrong version number in the registry key.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that command to switch the active thread, though. I'd expect it to run to the next source line for the current thread.