# Why does the CPU window always appear when trying to debug my project after a rebuild in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2010

Whenever I rebuild my application and try to step into a break-point the CPU window always appears. From what I understand the CPU window appears when DCU does not match up with the source file, however, in my case the DCU's are defintely being re-compiled and there are no old ones lying around or anything like that.

The strange thing here is if I close down the application and re-open the project, place the breakpoint and run it works fine. I can even modify files and just press F9 to run the project and it works fine....it only seems to be when I rebuild the project (via IDE Project menu or the project context menu) that this CPU window never breaks into the source (even though it can find it!).

I also noticed in the callstack a unit called `Generics` is always the top of the stack, never the unit my break point is in, this is no way related to where my break point is.

Any ideas?

Comment: But...rebuilding the project (via IDE project menu or context menu) doesn't execute it, it just builds. The only way to execute your build is to use F9/run. Are you saying that, from a fresh startup of Delphi, you can set the breakpoint, F9/run, and break into source, but then rebuilding (via menu), THEN pressing F9/run (to rebuild AGAIN and then RUN), your breakpoints break into the CPU window?

Answer (score 3):

Try checking your Delphi event log.

Sometimes Windows itself will write an `OutputDebugString` and then trigger a **breakpoint** when your application has done something very bad, e.g.:

```
HEAP[Project1.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block 32959a8 modified at 32959c0 after it was freed
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Project1.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, and indicates a bug in Project1.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
The output window may have more diagnostic information
```

It can also be Application Verifier (if you're using it; if you're not you should) telling you about a problem.

Comment: I haven't heard of application verifier so defintely not using it. I noticed now that the problem only ever occurs if I just build without compiling.

Comment: i still say check Delphi's event viewer. i've learned that whenever the CPU window unexpectedly appears for me: it's Windows, and Windows logs an OutputDebugString saying what's wrong.

Comment: Event viewer was the solution to me. The problem was "eap block at 00571D28 modified at 00571D5C past requested size of 2c" - I use DLL built in C - the problem was with a char* - I do malloc(len), not accounting for the terminating 0. I changed that to malloc(len+1) and no more cpu window. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178068/how-do-you-disable-the-cpu-window-in-delphi-7) I found suggestion to check `Ignore non-user breakpoints` in `Debugger Options` (D2009).

Comment: @straveu: I have tried this option still doesn't stop the CPU window from appearing.